# How do I recover my repos?

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, repository

I've messed up with repos. How do I get the default list of repos back? What about the keys I've probably have installed - but would not be used - if I'd roll back to the default repo list?

**Edit**:

Here's the full story. On updating to Kubuntu 12.04 - virtuoso-t started to give some error (it kubuntu tells me that is crashes on start up). I thought - re-installation would solve the problem. So I made a complete re-installation of `nepomuk`. I didn't notice - but it has also removed my kde! So on restart I've login to Gnome session. So I get to the Internet, opened a synaptic - and tried to install kubuntu-desktop. But it turns out to be a some dependency problem - nobody were to provide a plasma-desktop libs and so on. So I used the ubuntu repos generator (link is in the answers - I always get there by googling). But it didn't help. Finally I found a machine with Kubuntu 11.10 - I've started an update process - have waited until `/etc/apt` got updated, took it to my machine - no luck again: dependecy problems. Finally adding:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/ppa 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/beta
```

have solved it all.

Comment: Earlier: http://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: yes... but keyserver.ubuntu.com is kind of dead...

Comment: @Adobe keyserver.ubuntu.com is up on ports 80 and 11371. Are you sure that you don't have a firewall issue? What exactly do you mean by "messing up repos"? Installing third-party PPAs?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: `cat /etc/services | grep 80` gives `http            80/tcp          www             # WorldWideWeb HTTP`. Does it mean the the port 80 is open?

Comment: You cannot conclude that, `/etc/services` is used for mapping ports with their descriptive name.

Comment: `netstat -lutn` gives `tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a great site that will give you a listing of the defaults based upon your country and version in use:

http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/

Comment: I know the link. I tried it - after adding it all - I had some dependency problem issues - and could not install `kubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: And here's a [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/134943/21679) - where it says how can You add the keys - if You can't make it using keyserver.ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution, open `bash_history` file from your home folder, not sure what's equivalent of this file in KDE, and look for the PPAs you added manually using `sudo add-apt-repository`

Then, use `ppa-purge` (install it using `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`) to remove all those added PPAs that you've found in your bash_history file. For example, you've added Mozilla Security PPA using

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa`

Than you may use following command to remove the PPA and revert back to version of Firefox available in repositories of Ubuntu (12.04 in your case).

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntu-mozilla-security/ppa`

`sudo apt-get update`

**Note:** You'll not see the PPAs added manually from update manager, as `bash_history` is nothing but a log of all the commands you've executed in terminal since your installation. But you can use it to keep track if things you've performed using terminal (like adding PPAs).