# Can't add repo keys

Tags: 12.04, kubuntu, repository

I'm tring to add a keys (on Kubuntu 12.04)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys SOMEKEY
```

and I constantly get

```
gpg: requesting key 8AC93F7A from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

I thought my ports are closed. But the following should have made ports 80 and 11371 open:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 -s 0/0 --dport 11371 -j ACCEPT
```

But I still get `timed out`.

**Edit**:

The following solves it:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys SOMEKEY
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?  You need to add that so we can help you.

Comment: Kubuntu 12.04. I had the same problems in 11.10 and 11.04

Comment: I added the tags and edited your question with the info.

Comment: @Adobe To mark this question technically 'answered'; Kindly add an 'answer' and 'accept' it. You may need to wait a day or two to be able to accept your own answer,though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following solves it:

```
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys SOMEKEY
```

If you see something like this:

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com jaunty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
```

then add the appropriate key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
```

You can get a list of repos here: http://repogen.simplylinux.ch (but it is not recommended to add x-org updates - at least be sure to back up You `xorg.conf`)

If see errors from previous repos - empty your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` dir.

Answer (score 6):

This saved my life behind corporate proxy, hope it helps you too:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver-options http-proxy="http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_server_addr>:<proxy_port>" --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys <key_to_import>
```

Answer (score 0):

What helped me:

```
sudo -E apt-key adv --keyserver-options http-proxy="http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_server_addr>:<proxy_port>" --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys <key_to_import>
```

Comment: Same answer as https://askubuntu.com/a/591824/175814

Comment: the diff is sudo -E  perhaps is worth noting that I am using accessing the PC remotely - X11 forwarding over ssh

Answer (score 0):

Converting the server name to a proper URL as below worked for me.

> sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys SOMEKEY

Answer (score 0):

For me, i removed my custom /etc/apt/source.list (which not including the official ubuntu source) and recovered the origin default one back. And that it done!