# can't add key - keyserver timed out

Tags: apt, updates, repository, mongodb

I'm trying to install mongodb on ubuntu 15.10. 
While following this - [Install Mongo 3.2 on Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/724749/install-mongo-3-2-on-ubuntu-15-10) - i got the following error message:

```
W: GPG error: http://repo.mongodb.org trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY D68FA50FEA312927
```

So then I attempted to add the key like this:

```
me@devbox:/etc/test$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D68FA50FEA312927

Executing: gpg --ignore-time-conflict --no-options --no-default-keyring --homedir /tmp/tmp.CWnpUGSg5w --no-auto-check-trustdb --trust-model always --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --primary-keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/apt.postgresql.org.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/nginx_ubuntu_stable.gpg --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/webupd8team_ubuntu_java.gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D68FA50FEA312927
gpg: requesting key EA312927 from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: keyserver timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: keyserver error
```

Not sure what else to try.  I'm currently looking other posts here on this  site to see if this has been addressed.

EDIT 1:

Based on this post:  [Can't add repo keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/134913/cant-add-repo-keys)

I tried to run the command :

```
sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys D68FA50FEA312927
```

and then retried:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys D68FA50FEA312927
```

But it's still failing.

Comment: sudo apt-key adv --keyserver-options http-proxy="http://<username>:<password>@<proxy_server_addr>:<proxy_port>" --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys <key_to_import>

Comment: Your internet had problem and yiu can't see the key server . Please try with this refrence :
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-14-04
If not solved . I suggest download mongodb .deb file from mongodb offical sites and install them from local

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Can you reach keyserver.ubuntu.com with a plain TCP connection (`telnet keyserver.ubuntu.com 80`)?

Answer (score 0):

Try different keyservers, and try using port 80.

A few servers you could try if `keyserver.ubuntu.com` doesn't work :

- keys.gnupg.net (this one worked for me today)
- pgp.mit.edu
- sks-keyservers.net
- keyserver.pgp.com

```sh
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://$pgp_server:80 --recv-keys $wanted_key
```